# error TS2345: Argument of type '{ cluster: string; encrypted: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to complete a chatbot for an exhibition. the error is as follows:

```sh
Error: src/app/services/pusher.service.ts:13:5 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ cluster: string; encrypted: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'encrypted' does not exist in type 'Options'.

13     encrypted: true
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
    
// this is here to discourage the instantianting of pusher any where its
// needed, better to reference it from one place
@Injectable()
export class PusherService {
    private _pusher: any;
    
    constructor() {
      this._pusher = new Pusher ('APP_KEY', {
        cluster: 'eu',
        encrypted: true
      });
    }
    
    getPusher() {
      return this._pusher;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Fintan and welcome to stackoverflow!

The error tells you what you need to know: the options you provide include a property  'encrypted' but it's not expected to be in there.

I've no idea what pusher-js is all about but you can read about all possible properties for the options [here](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/connection#channels-options-parameter). Two things I found in the documentation:

First, you may want to specify the 'forceTLS' property:

```
this._pusher = new Pusher ('APP_KEY', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    forceTLS: true
});
```

Second, you may want to change your import to use encrypted channels:

Switch

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
```

to

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/with-encryption';
```

and you're good to go.